# what does "net_ratelnet_ratelimit: 222 callbacks suppressed" mean?

Tags: syslog

The application is still responsive, but when I ssh into the server i cant do anything because errors keep popping up.

Answer (score 1):

> i cant do anything because errors keep popping up.

You can use `dmesg` to fix that, [man dmesg](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmesg):

> ```
>    -n level
>           Set the level at which logging of messages is done to the console.
>           For example, -n 1 prevents all messages, except panic messages,
>           from appearing on the console.
> ```

Also, suppresing means that some identical warning's repeating way too much. I hope you'll be able to find out what warning it was having applied dmesg to stop console mess.